# Spark Matrix multiplication with python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to do matrix multiplication using Apache Spark and Python.

Here is my data

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
```

My RDD of vectors

```
rows_1 = sc.parallelize([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]])
rows_2 = sc.parallelize([[1, 2], [4, 5]])
```

My maxtrix

```
mat1 = RowMatrix(rows_1)
mat2 = RowMatrix(rows_2)
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
mat = mat1 * mat2
```

I wrote a function to process the matrix multiplication but I'm afraid to have a long processing time. Here is my function:

```
def matrix_multiply(df1, df2):
    nb_row = df1.count()    
    mat=[]
    for i in range(0, nb_row):
        row=list(df1.filter(df1['index']==i).take(1)[0])
        row_out = []
        for r in range(0, len(row)):
            r_value = 0
            col = df2.select(df2[list_col[r]]).collect()
            col = [list(c)[0] for c in col]
            for c in range(0, len(col)): 
                r_value += row[c] * col[c]
            row_out.append(r_value)            
        mat.append(row_out)
    return mat
```

My function make a lot of spark actions (take, collect, etc.). Does the function will take a lot of processing time?
If someone have another idea it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot. Since `RowMatrix` has no meaningful row indices it cannot be used for multiplications. Even ignoring that the only distributed matrix [which supports multiplication with another distributed structure](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix.multiply) is `BlockMatrix`.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import *

def as_block_matrix(rdd, rowsPerBlock=1024, colsPerBlock=1024):
    return IndexedRowMatrix(
        rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda xi: IndexedRow(xi[1], xi[0]))
    ).toBlockMatrix(rowsPerBlock, colsPerBlock)

as_block_matrix(rows_1).multiply(as_block_matrix(rows_2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it does not work for me. I'm using Spark 1.5.0. Here is the error message: **AttributeError: 'BlockMatrix' object has no attribute 'multiply'**

Comment: It has been introduced in 1.6.

Comment: Ok I see. I create a function to process it (see the post above).

Comment: I'm getting a `SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure` on the line `rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda xi: IndexedRow(xi[1], xi[0]))`