# pyspark.mllib DenseMatrix multiplication

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, matrix-multiplication

I have to do matrix multiplication in PySpark but can't find how to do it with `DenseMatrix`. For example

```py
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseMatrix

Q = DenseMatrix(nfeatures, nfeatures, [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
w = DenseMatrix(nfeatures, 1, [0, 0, 0])
print( Q * w )
```

results in the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'DenseMatrix' and 'DenseMatrix'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a method for doing matrix multiplication? What is the usual way of doing this with PySpark streaming?

Best regards,
Noelia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `pyspark.ml.linalg.Matrix` nor `pyspark.mllib.linalg.Matrix` implements matrix multiplication. These classes are used mostly as an exchange formats for `mllib` / `ml` algorithms and are not designed to be used as full featured data structures for linear algebra.

If you need something more than to pass data to some ML / MLlib algorithm just use standard NumPy / SciPy stack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume once we conver `toArray()` to use the standard numpy linalg functions, we are giving up on any potential parallelisation while multiplication? I saw your response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766213/spark-matrix-multiplication-with-python), where you suggest using BlockMatrix. Can the poster not convert to BlockMatrix and do the multiplication in a parallelised way there?

Comment: @Rhubarb `pyspark.{ml|mllib}.linalg.DenseMatrix` is not distributed at all. Parallelization will depend on the underlaying linear algebra library. Regarding conversion to `BlockMatrix` - as long as data fits in memory matrix multiplication with good native bindings will order(s) of magnitude faster. So conversion like this rarely makes sense. But technically speaking it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was thinking. As long as it fits into memory, no point in trying to 'parallelise' a vectorised operation. Right?

Comment: @Rhubarb Yeah. This is typically true for any small structure.