# Multiply two numpy matrices in PySpark

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have these two Numpy arrays:

```
A = np.arange(1024 ** 2, dtype=np.float64).reshape(1024, 1024)
B = np.arange(1024 ** 2, dtype=np.float64).reshape(1024, 1024)
```

and I perform the following on them:

```
np.sum(np.dot(A, B))
```

Now, I'd like to be able to essentially perform the same calculation with the same matrices using PySpark in order to achieve a distributed calculation with my Spark cluster.

Does anyone know or have a sample that does something along these lines in PySpark?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Seems relevant https://labs.yodas.com/large-scale-matrix-multiplication-with-pyspark-or-how-to-match-two-large-datasets-of-company-1be4b1b2871e#.u0khat9gy

Comment: Perhaps, but I am unfortunately unable to apply that solution to my question.  It seems to use different libraries and is a word/text based problem.

Comment: Well are your matrices dense or sparse? And are A and B really 1024×1024 or larger?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, kennytm.  A & B can be larger, but 1024x1024 should work for my testing.  The size of the matrix really isn't my concern.  Also, these are numpy arrays and I believe they can be easily converted into dense matrices, so am fine doing that, if it is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `as_block_matrix` method from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766213/spark-matrix-multiplication-with-python), you could do the following (but see the comment of @kennytm why this method can be slow for bigger matrices):

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
A = np.arange(1024 ** 2, dtype=np.float64).reshape(1024, 1024)
B = np.arange(1024 ** 2, dtype=np.float64).reshape(1024, 1024)

from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import *

def as_block_matrix(rdd, rowsPerBlock=1024, colsPerBlock=1024):
    return IndexedRowMatrix(
        rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda xi: IndexedRow(xi[1], xi[0]))
    ).toBlockMatrix(rowsPerBlock, colsPerBlock)

matrixA = as_block_matrix(sc.parallelize(A))
matrixB = as_block_matrix(sc.parallelize(B))
product = matrixA.multiply(matrixB)
```