# Unable to create BlockMatrix in PySpark: "Job aborted due to stage failure"

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to multiply a matrix by a vector in PySpark. In my understanding, this should be possible by using PySpark's [`BlockMatrix.multiply()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest//api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix.multiply) function.

However, I'm unable to create a `BlockMatrix` in the first place. Using this simplified code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import BlockMatrix
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([[0,1], [1,2]])
blockMatrx = BlockMatrix(rdd, 4000, 4000)
```

Causes the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-360ec98840e3> in <module>
      1 rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([[0,1], [1,2]])
----> 2 blockMatrx = BlockMatrix(rdd, 4000, 4000)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyspark\mllib\linalg\distributed.py in __init__(self, blocks, rowsPerBlock, colsPerBlock, numRows, numCols)
   1215             # ((blockRowIndex, blockColIndex), sub-matrix) tuples on
   1216             # the Scala side.
-> 1217             java_matrix = callMLlibFunc("createBlockMatrix", blocks.toDF(),
   1218                                         int(rowsPerBlock), int(colsPerBlock),
   1219                                         int(numRows), int(numCols))

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in toDF(self, schema, sampleRatio)
     64         [Row(name='Alice', age=1)]
     65         """
---> 66         return sparkSession.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
     67 
     68     RDD.toDF = toDF

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    673             return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(
    674                 data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
--> 675         return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    676 
    677     def _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    696 
    697         if isinstance(data, RDD):
--> 698             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    699         else:
    700             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in _createFromRDD(self, rdd, schema, samplingRatio)
    484         """
    485         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 486             struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio, names=schema)
    487             converter = _create_converter(struct)
    488             rdd = rdd.map(converter)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in _inferSchema(self, rdd, samplingRatio, names)
    458         :class:`pyspark.sql.types.StructType`
    459         """
--> 460         first = rdd.first()
    461         if not first:
    462             raise ValueError("The first row in RDD is empty, "

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in first(self)
   1584         ValueError: RDD is empty
   1585         """
-> 1586         rs = self.take(1)
   1587         if rs:
   1588             return rs[0]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1564 
   1565             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1566             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1567 
   1568             items += res

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   1231         # SparkContext#runJob.
   1232         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
-> 1233         sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   1234         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
   1235 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (192.168.2.79 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:535)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:189)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:174)
    ... 14 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2253)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2202)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2440)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2382)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2202)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2223)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2242)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:535)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:189)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:174)
    ... 14 more
```

**Background**

The reason for multiplying these two is to implement the Page Rank algorithm in parallel. The sequential algorithm, which I've implemented successfully, does something like this:

```
...
for i in range(num_iterations):
   v = M_hat @ v
return v
```

Where `v` is an eigenvector and `M_hat` is the sparse matrix of pages and the links between them. I've not been able to build up the intuition to correctly understand how this program can be done in parallel using RDDs, even though people do [give examples](https://bigtony666.github.io/page-rank-in-spark/). Specifically, I'm not sure how the loop above is done in parallel.

`BlockMatrix` is not meant for sparse matrices; however, [`multiply()` has not been implemented on sparse matrices in PySpark.](https://medium.com/@rantav/large-scale-matrix-multiplication-with-pyspark-or-how-to-match-two-large-datasets-of-company-1be4b1b2871e) As I research ways to multiply matrices in PySpark [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889965/multiply-two-numpy-matrices-in-pyspark)[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766213/spark-matrix-multiplication-with-python)[(3)](https://bmeyers.github.io/Spark_sparse_matrix_mult/), I'm either unable to understand them, or they error out.

For full disclosure, this is an assignment. However, I've been researching about three days with little success, because the teacher has only quickly introduced Spark, and I'm extremely poor at understanding mathematical matrix operations.

**Question**

Make this work:

```
blockMatrx = BlockMatrix(rdd, 4000, 4000)
```

**Update**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766213/spark-matrix-multiplication-with-python) looks promising:

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

rows_1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]])
rows_2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([[1, 2], [4, 5]])

def as_block_matrix(rdd, rowsPerBlock=1024, colsPerBlock=1024):
    return IndexedRowMatrix(
        rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda xi: IndexedRow(xi[1], xi[0]))
    ).toBlockMatrix(rowsPerBlock, colsPerBlock)

as_block_matrix(rows_1).multiply(as_block_matrix(rows_2))
```

However, I still get a `SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure` exception on the line `rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda xi: IndexedRow(xi[1], xi[0]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53192485/4682228) from another question, installing a different version of the Java JDK worked.

```
conda install -c cyclus java-jdk
```

I don't exactly know why, since mine was the latest version from Oracle, and my PySpark version was 3.1.1.