# How to do matrix multiplication in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `user's` "taste" vector:

```
+------+--------------------+
|userId|      scaledFeatures|
+------+--------------------+
|    18|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|
|    65|[0.0,0.0023910733...|
|    96|[0.0,0.0,0.005268...|
|   121|[0.0,0.0021253985...|
|   129|[0.0,0.0029224229...|
+------+--------------------+
```

And `movie's` content vectors:

```
+-------+--------------------+
|movieId|      scaledFeatures|
+-------+--------------------+
|      1|[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|
|      2|[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|
|      3|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|
|      4|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|
|      5|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|
+-------+--------------------+
```

How to take `user's` taste vector by its `userId` and multiply with `movie's` content table in pyspark? so I can get the most similar movies by `movieId`?

Comment: your question is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766213/spark-matrix-multiplication-with-python.please remove question if its answers your question

Comment: its quite similar but I still can't figure it out how to implement it.